# Can I use the new VS 2011 to publish Windows XP Compatible Programs?

Tags: visual-studio, backwards-compatibility, software-distribution, windows-8

Can I use Visual Studio 2011 running on the Windows 8 Developer Preview to publish programs that will not only run on Windows 8, but that will run on Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8? I know that using Visual Studio 2010 while Running XP can produce applications that will run on XP and up, but can it work the other way?

**UPDATE:** By Publish I mean that I want to package my application into an installer and distribute it.
I am Using Visual Basic .NET as the programing language within Visual Studio 2011

**UPDATE 2:** Also, If I can't make my app available on XP through 8, then can I use Visual Studio 2010 to do this or is it a matter of Operating Systems?

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"?

Comment: That all rather depends on what language you're talking about and what the actual shipping version of VS2011 will look like.  XP is starting to get phased out, the CRT no longer supports it for example.  You'll have to wait until RTM.

Comment: @Pavel and at Hans I have update the question, I need to be able to distribute my app and it's in Visual Basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of VS11 that comes in the Win8 DP will only let you build Win8 apps.  You can install VS2010 side by side with it though to do other types of development.

Comment: You mean VS11 Express? Note that there is also a full version of VS11 beta available to MSDN subscribers, which lets you do everything you could do with VS2010.

Comment: I don't think the full VS11 beta can be installed side-by-side with the Express version that Win8 DP comes with.

Comment: @RobertLevy so if I install VS2010 Express on Win8, I can still develop for XP thru 7?

Comment: @RobertLevy Yes, it can. Express has always been installable side-by-side with other VS editions, and VS11 is no exception. Furthermore, MSDN subscribers can download a Win8 install DVD and have a clean install of Win8, without Express.

Comment: @RazorSharp You can install VS2010 (any edition) on Win8, and use it to develop for all previous Windows versions. Or you can install non-Express VS11 (if you have MSDN subscription) and do the same.

Comment: @PavelMinaev Thank You! That is very helpful! And just to check, Windows 8 is SAFE to develop on even though it's in Alpha stage?

Comment: @RazorSharp "Safe" in what sense?

Comment: @PavelMinaev Safe as in: it won't ruin my computer or hardrive